# Remove SPGroups from SP 2013 On-Prem SiteCollection -Special Case

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, spgroup

When an item is added in the list, I need to create 4 SPGroups dynamically with the title of the SPList fetched in the ItemAdded method.

Due to some mistakes in the event receiver code, the number of spgroups were created in hundreds instead of 4.

Now I need to remove the unwanted 300+ groups created in this site collection.
For this, I have created a powershell script to retrieve all the SPGroups from the site collection and wanna delete the same.

How to segregate the existing groups with the unwanted ones.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$site = Get-SPSite "http://srvr001:28516/" 
$groups = $site.RootWeb.sitegroups
$COUNGRP= $groups.COUNT
$mdate=  get-date -f yyyy/MM/dd-HHmm
Write-Host $mdate
$xportedfilename = "E:\PoCSolutions\spgroupsfromsite" + "_$mdate.csv"
foreach ($grp in $groups)
{
    $grp.name | Out-File  $xportedfilename  -Append 
    #foreach ($user in $grp.users) {"  User: " + $user.name}
}
$site.Dispose()
```

and i have generated  an excel file based on the groups fetched from site.
Now i am stuck with , how to split these spgroups names with semicolon, or double-quotes, comma delimiter.
below is the  csv file with line by line , generated from my ps script:

```
11 Product Development Team Members
123aaa Product Development Team Members
12 Product Development Team Members
21MARNewDepartment Team Members
30may test again Product Development Team Members
a1 Product Development Team Members
a2 Product Development Team Members
aa1 Product Development Team Members
aa2 Product Development Team Members
aaa123 Product Development Team Members
aaa Product Development Team Members
aa Product Development Team Members
ab Product Development Team Members
ALLFHGROUPS
ALLNPHGROUPS
Approvers
APRIL08_NPD_NEW_DEPARTMENT Team Members
APRIL08_WIRESNCABLES_DEPARTMENT_NEW Team Members
a Product Development Team Members
ax Product Development Team Members
az Product Development Team Members
BenchmarkIndex_Read
b Product Development Team Members
```

above are some of the junk groups created and i wanna remove them.
how to achieve this?

Comment: Think in terms of Created Date for SharePoint Group. Hope this helps http://www.duanqu.tech/questions/3044484/retrieve-the-creator-user-and-created-date-of-a-sharepoint-group

Comment: @Asad Refai,can you pls elaborate ,to edit this question to make the lines of ps script in this editor , perfectly? Doyou use any other editor to format the code?

Comment: my doubt is, how to make the entries in the csv file with a delimiter? like double-quotes and  , comma delimiter.  my idea is such that i can put these in an array or hash and  iterate through it and delete from site .

Comment: @SaMolPP My intention was to make things even more readable. Also the csv file data was not readable at all.

Comment: also, am having a issue with the csv,  how can i make this as an array of names, using notepad++ :-) , so that i will declare these as an array of  powershell variable and loop through these  groups ? any notepad++ tricks such that all these items  are replaced with "group1", "group2" ... sorry am ignorant here!! am a novice in excel/vba tricks !  :-(